# cuda and opengl - efficiency problem

Tags: opengl, gpgpu, cuda

I wonder why a way to initialize vbo make a big difference in fps when interacting with cuda.
When I create vbo there are two possibilities:

- vbo reserves only memory space with the given data size (in this case positions of the particles are
  first time write to vbo within the kernel and later modify in the kernel):

  ```
  gl.glBufferData(GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, n_particles * 4 * Sizeof.FLOAT, null, GL3.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  ```
- vbo reserves memory space with the given data size and get some initial data (positions of the particles - ofcourse these values are later modify in the kernel)

  ```
  gl.glBufferData(GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, n_particles * 4 * Sizeof.FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(particlesPositions), GL3.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  ```

1.~408 fps 2. ~75 fps

You can check this behaviour using a Simple OpenGL example from Nvidia GPU Computing SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first case doesn't have to upload data to the GPU. The second case does.

It's the difference between:

```
void *memory = malloc(size);
```

and

```
void *memory = malloc(size);
memcpy(memory, data, size);
```

The first is necessarily faster than the second.

Also, you may wish to use `GL_STREAM_DRAW` instead of `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` if you're frequently calling `glBufferData` on the same buffer object.

Comment: But in the second case I initialize vbo once before the rendering in my init function  - then vertices are placed in the gpu memory. In first case I don't initialize vbo on the host side, but later kernel also put vertices int the gpu memory. There is no data transfer during the rendering.

Comment: @Lynx: Maybe NVIDIA's implementation puts the buffer in different memory if you give it an initial value. There's no way to be sure. Just be glad you found a fast path; NVIDIA's implementations can be kinda tricky that way.

Comment: What do you mean by "different memory" ? The difference in fps is so big that there should be some reasonable explanation.

Comment: @Lynx: The driver can allocate a buffer object wherever it wants. System memory, GPU memory, etc. And no, there doesn't have to be a "reasonable" explanation. NVIDIA's drivers can be kind of touchy when it comes to buffer objects.

Comment: I'm not OpenGL expert but as far as I know the main advantage of vbo over other methods is storing vertices in a gpu memory which gives the best rendering results. And becasue of that vbo was introduced. But as you mentioned above there is no guarantee where driver allocates the buffer. So what are performance benefits of using vbo when data is storing outside a gpu memory? It makes no sense. Could you give me some explanation ?

Comment: @Lynx: The point is that the driver can allocate the memory wherever it wants. Which, presumably, is a place that is best for your particular needs. If you're doing a lot of re-uploading to the same buffer, then that may not be on the GPU.

Comment: Is there any way to force the memory location ? The only thing seems to be a suggestion which I send as the last argument in glBufferData. But that is some kind of hint.

Comment: @Lynx: It _is_ a hint. It has no affect on the actual behavior; it will only affect performance. As I said, NVIDIA's implementation is tricky, so you will simply have to try stuff to see how it works. I've heard reports that DYNAMIC_DRAW is a bad idea for buffers on NVIDIA drivers, so consider STREAM_DRAW.